# Анроид сохранить значение, чтобы было доступно phonegap

Tags: android

Вобщем пришел к выводу что надо писать свой плагин, для работы в фоне.
Думаю в фоне будет работать сервис, который будет загружать данные на текущий день.
и вот вопрос, куда их сохранять, чтобы был доступ к ним из phonegap
я обычно в phonegap сохраняю данные в localstore
может ли android дотянуться до localstore и если можно пример как?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы файлы были доступны для всех приложений (независимо от среды разработки), их нужно сохранять во внешней памяти - [сохранение файлов](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru). От туда они читаются обычным потоком ввода-вывода (не знаю, что он из себя представляет в PhoneGap).